# Stanford's StanfordCPPLib on Linux

Tags: opensuse, gcc, c++

I'm using SUSE Linux 13.1 and self studying Stanford's CS 106B course. Here I have found the following `zip` file, [cs106b-hw2-ngrams-starter-files.zip](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs106b/homework/2-ngrams/cs106b-hw2-ngrams-starter-files.zip), and downloaded.

#### Now questions

1. This libs are for Windows, so some changes will be needed to make them work correctly in Linux. What changes?
2. Where to put this folder, so that `gcc` compiler could automatically find this libs?

Comment: My experience has been that porting CPP code written for Microsoft Windows to Linux is non-trivial.  The gpp compiler plain simply will not allow a lot of constructions MSVC allows.

Comment: Ask if there is a Linux version (or alternative) available. If not, perhaps offer your help (band together with some classmates) to get it done. But don't count on it being done for the term...